# jQuery datepicker settings not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

In jQuery Date picker i write like this for getting date value. But i want to write **min Date,Change Month etc.** where should i place the settings. when i wrote it inside function it doesn't display. Please help me

```
  $(function() {
  $('#datepicker').datepicker({onSelect: function()
       { 
        var dateObject = $(this).val(); 
        alert(dateObject);

      }

        });
    });

  </script>
```

I wrote in

```
<script>

  $(function() {
  $('#datepicker').datepicker({minDate:+0,changeMonth:true,onSelect: function()
       { 
        var dateObject = $(this).val(); 
        alert(dateObject);

      }

        });
    });

  </script>
```

Comment: Your settings in the second script are correct.

Comment: what do you want to display? do you want to display the value of minDate in the onSelect handler

Comment: @billyonecan 0 and +0 are the same thing.

Comment: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Answer (score 1):

To alert the selected date you need to use `getdate`.

```
var dateObject = $("#datepicker").datepicker('getDate'); 
alert(dateObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

onSelect has parameter with the value
try use it like this:

```
onSelect: function(value) { alert(value) }
```

Comment: where should i add minDate,DateFormat etc..?

Answer (score 0):

```
        onSelect: function (dateText, instance) {

        }
```